# Why does my subtotal code counts 1 when there's no values?

Tags: excel, vba, count, subtotal

so I'm running a code that filters my data and then takes the count of the data and inserts it into an excel file. I'm using this code to count the data:

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range("A2:A" & lastrow))
```

For some reason, when I've filtered my data so that no value is visible aside from my top row, which is located in row 1, It gives me a value of 1 rather than 0. Any ideas why it's doing so?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of lastrow when that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a funny thing I, too, discovered a while ago. What's happening is that, with a blank (or just filtered to *appear* blank) column A, `lastrow = 1`, which means the range you're Subtotaling is `Range("A2:A1")`.

For example, test:

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range("A2:A1"))
```

Comment: This is the answer. Note that Excel automatically flips `A2:A1` to `A1:A2` (try it in a cell!). Thus, OP needs to explicitly make `count` be `0` when `lastRow` is `1` - otherwise they're counting their header row. Alternatively, subtotal `"A1:A" & lastRow`, and systematically subtract 1 from that.